# I need help converting awk to stand alone bash script

Tags: bash, awk

Need help converting the following to stand alone code.

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[NR,i] = $i} }
    NF>p { p = NF }
    END {
        for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
            str=a[1,j]
            for(i=2; i<=NR; i++)
        {str=str"   "a[i,j];}
        printf str"\n"}
    }' $temp_input
```

Clarification: I meant stand alone bash script not utilizing AWK. I wrote this utilizing AWK but cant figure out how to structure this without AWK. I played around with this to get it to work, it does but can never replicate this in Bash script. that is why i said stand alone code.

the end format of the returned data never matches when AWK is translated into Bash. it appears to be the same however during testing they are different when writen in Bash not using AWK.

Comment: You need to explain the meaning of "stand alone code."

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: I meant stand alone bash script not utilizing AWK. I wrote this utilizing AWK but cant figure out how to structure this in AWK.  I played around with this to get it to work, it does but can never replicate this in Bash script. that is why i said stand alone code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question correctly. If you want a script that executes that `awk` code on whatever file is supplied as a parameter, you don't need `bash` at all; you can just make an `awk` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[NR,i] = $i} }
NF>p { p = NF }
END {
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++)
    {str=str"   "a[i,j];}
    printf str"\n"}
}
```

If you want a `bash` wrapper around it, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {a[NR,i] = $i} }
    NF>p { p = NF }
    END {
        for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
            str=a[1,j]
            for(i=2; i<=NR; i++)
        {str=str"   "a[i,j];}
        printf str"\n"}
    }' "$@"
```

(Note that `"$@"` is the standard way to pass on parameter(s) passed to the script.)

In either case, you should add execute permission to the script (e.g. if you named the script `rotatefields`, you'd use `chmod +x rotatefields`). Then either place it in one of the directories in your `$PATH` and just run it by name (e.g. `rotatefields filetorotate`), or run it from the same directory it's in with `./rotatefields filetorotate`, or if it's in some other directory specify the full path (`/path/to/rotatefields filetorotate`).

(Note: Do *not* run them with `sh rotatefields` -- that overrides the shebang line and runs it with plain `sh`, which can cause trouble.)

Comment: Assuming OP makes a file called `test.sh`, how would OP pass a parameter? `test.sh <file>`?

Comment: @CPak Either use `./test.sh <file>`, or place it in a directory in `$PATH`; see update. Also, using extensions like `.sh` on commands isn't really recommended; the system will ignore them and use the shebang line to determine what interpreter to run them with.

Comment: Not understanding the question is why you shouldn't answer questions that aren't clear and you should have voted to close it instead of wasting your time answering it. I thought you would have known better owing to your rep count.